# Look for Table inside a HTML VBA

Tags: vba

Have the below block of code ...I have 5 tables this responds with but I am interested only in one of the table in the page ...I needed only one table data (a specific one) which the below responds .

I tried  "For Each tbl In ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("rgMasterTable") to get that specific table but this gives me object not supported run time error . How will you get a specific table from a HTMl page which has multiple "TABLE" tags

```
      For Each tbl In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
            tabno = tabno + 1
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)
            rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
            For Each rw In tbl.Rows
                For Each cl In rw.Cells
                    rng.Value = cl.outerText
                    Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                    I = I + 1
                Next cl
                nextrow = nextrow + 1
                Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I)
                I = 0
            Next rw
        Next tbl

        ws.Cells.ClearFormats
```

The HTML code looks like this

table class="rgMasterTable" border="0" id="ctl00_ContentBody_rgridCDPList_ctl00" style="width:100%;table-layout:auto;empty-cells:show;"

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim tbl
Set tbl = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_rgridCDPList_ctl00")
```

should give you that specific table